# Java, почему с == 2?

Tags: java, многопоточность, volatile

```
public class VolatileTest {
    static int a = 0;
    static int b = 0;
    static int c = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         new MyThread1().start();
         new MyThread2().start();
         Thread.currentThread().sleep(50);
         System.out.println("c: " + c);


    }
    static  class MyThread1 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int r1 = a;
            System.out.println("r1: " + r1);

            int v = c;
            v++;
            c = v;
            b = 1;
        }  
    }

    static class MyThread2 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int r2 = b;
            System.out.println("r2: " + r2);
            int v = c;
            v++;
            c = v;
            a = 1;
        }  
    }   
}
```

Почему `С == 2` после выполнения `main` и как можно сделать чтобы `r1` и `r2` всегда были нулями?

Comment: Наверное, c == 2, потому что два потока отработали и каждый увеличил переменную на 1, а изначально она была равна нулю?

Comment: да логично)  просто пытаюсь  сделать такой пример чтобы нужно обозначить переменную как volatile и заодно сразу рассмотреть happens-before order с помощью volatile

Comment: @fox.ontour, Хороший пример: https://dzone.com/articles/java-volatile-keyword-0

Answer (score 2):

Тело треда очень маленькое и первый тред успевает отработать до того, как начнет работать второй. Поэтому, с и равно 2. Если же хочется, что бы все было "более ожидаемо" (я не говорю, что оно будет правильнее и действительно ожидаемие), добавьте sleep между строками с произвольными (полученными у random) значениями.

> как можно сделать чтобы r1 и r2 всегда были нулями?

присвоить им явно ноль и не трогать.

Comment: я просто уже запутался, потоки вроде как должны кэшировать переменные и каждый поток должен работать со своим кэшом и поэтому они вроде как должны были изменить только свой кэш а не основную переменную или когда поток заканчивается он весь свой кэш переписывает в основную память?

Comment: ничего не должны кешироваться. Переменная это просто место в памяти. И если кто то один пишет, то второй рано или поздно прочитает.

Comment: @fox.ontour: Потоки не _должны_ кешировать переменные. Они _имеют право_ кешировать переменные.

Comment: То есть когда посчитают необходимым?

Comment: Все зависит от архитектуры JVM и реализации JDK. Вроде у Oracle JDK и на обычных процессорах сложно получить примеры, которые вы хотите.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class VolatileTest {

    static int c = 0;
    final static int MAX_CNT=100000;
    final static int THREAD_CNT=10;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Thread[] threads = new MyThread[THREAD_CNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_CNT; i++) {
            threads[i] = new MyThread();
        }
        Thread.sleep(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_CNT; i++) {
            threads[i].start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < THREAD_CNT; i++) {
            threads[i].join();
        }

        System.out.println("c: " + c);

    }
    static  class MyThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i<MAX_CNT; i++) {
                int x=new Random().nextInt();
                c++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Во-первых увеличиваем число циклов и тредов. Во-вторых с++ уже сама по себе выполняет сначала чтение, потом увеличение, потом запись - нет необходимости вводить дополнительные переменные, операция ++ уже не обеспечивает атомарность. Кроме того, строка int x=new Random().nextInt();  защищает от оптимизаций - потому что компилятор имеет право заранее вычислить результат цикла и подставить готовое значение. Эта строка по крайней мере в моем случае защищала от этого. Вот в результате еще ни разу не получил значение 1000000
Кстати, обратите внимание что даже volatile не спасет в данном случае.